# How to create dynamic field names in a wordpress widget

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a WordPress widget plugin with a settings form of HTML checkboxes. Each checkbox corresponds to a different `post_type`. This is my code:

```
function form($instance) {
   $defaults   = array( 'num_posts' => 5 );
   $instance   = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );
   $num_posts  = $instance['num_posts'];
   $post_types = get_post_types();
   $instance['post_types'] = $post_types;
   ?>

<p>Number of posts to show: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'num_posts' ); ?>" type="number" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $num_posts ); ?>" /></p>
    <p>Filter by Post Type: <ul>
    <?php foreach ($post_types as $post_type) { ?>
        <li><input name="<?php echo $post_type; ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $post_types, 'on' ); ?> /><label for="<?php echo $post_type; ?>" /><?php echo $post_type; ?></label></li>
    <?php
    } ?>
    </ul></p>
```

My question is, how do I generate dynamic `$instance` names for the checkboxes in the loop? I realize I should be able to do something like `$this->get_field_name( 'myname' );`, but how to make that dynamic?

**NOTE:** The above code sample simply outputs the `post_type` for the name property instead of using `get_field_name`; this is not a solution, just a wall I hit.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I narrowed the issue to the widget update function, which doesn't seem to work when using a foreach loop. Another unanswered issue on stackoverflow describes something similar. [PHP - Wordpress - Plugin Widget Update Function - Update array values [Foreach Loop not Working]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948682/php-wordpress-plugin-widget-update-function-update-array-values-foreach-l)

Here's my code (slightly revised) including the update function.

```
    // build the widget settings form
function form( $instance ) {
    $defaults   = array( 'num_posts' => 5 );
    $instance   = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );
    $num_posts  = $instance['num_posts'];

    foreach ( get_post_types() as $post_type ) {
        $post_types_array[$post_type] = $post_type;
    }

    $instance['post_types'] = $post_types_array;
    $post_types = $instance['post_types'];

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($instance);
    echo '</pre>';
    ?>

        <p>Number of posts to show: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'num_posts' ); ?>" type="number" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $num_posts ); ?>" /></p>
        <p>Filter by Post Type: <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) { ?>
            <li><input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( $post_type ); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $this->get_field_name( $post_type ) ); ?> /><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( $post_type ); ?>" /><?php echo $post_type; ?></label></li>
        <?php
       } ?>
        </ul></p>

    <?php
}

// save the widget settings
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['num_posts'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['num_posts'] );

    foreach ( $instance['post_types'] as $post_type ) {
        $instance['post_types'][$post_type] = strip_tags( $new_instance['post_types'][$post_type] );
    }

    return $instance;
}
```

Comment: I think you missed a few steps within the update function.  Check out my fully functional code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870224/checkbox-array-in-wordpress-widget